# If there is no activity on a question I post, can I permanently wipe it out of the SO database?

Tags: support

While it's easy enough to delete a question I post that has no user interaction (other than downvotes), can I make it so that the question was never asked in the first place?

Not a big deal. Just curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posts are <s>rarely</s> never *permanently* deleted from the database, so the direct answer to your question is "no".

The vast majority of users (those under 10,000 reputation) cannot see deleted posts anyway, and would not be able to readily find it on the site, so it is *effectively* removed from existence.

Comment: Also deleted questions aren't linked to from user profiles so they're very hard to find unless you have the URL.

Comment: Rarely is still too much credit here. It's true some were permanently deleted long ago when the site first started, but it's never happened since then. The absolutely true answer is *never*, not *rarely*.

Comment: @animuson:  Thanks for clarifying that; I'll acquiesce.

Comment: @animuson never?  You have never had a court order you to permanently delete something?

Comment: @MartinJames: A court order usually *prevents* one from deleting things...

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible. We don't offer permanent and complete deletion of content.

Comment: I guess deletion + disassociation is the closest you can get

Comment: @Patrice We don't disassociate deleted content. It's pretty pointless and a waste of time.

Comment: Oh it most definitely is. I just thought it was possible to do. Thx for the clarification!